# How to change targeted android version of cordova?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, android-sdk-tools

When typed `cordova platfom is`, it returns android 6.3.0 version.But the problem is that I haven't downloaded that version in my android sdk and so, it tells me to install android target of api level android-26.

[image: Asks for installing Android-26 api level]

In order to avoid that, I wanted to change it to android@5.0.1 but it gave me a huge error message in red; but when typed `cordova platform add android`/`cordova platform add android@6.3.0`, it fetches all the data and adds that to *config.xml* also.

**here is whats installed in my android sdk:**

[image: android sdk, showing installed stuff]

I am a beginner, plz help the best way you can for me and all those who have or 'will' have same problem.Thanks a lot

Comment: Just download the API 26 SDK - it will be far easier.

Comment: actually my this `cordova requirements` problem is solved by changing android version from *6.3.0* to *5.0.1* in every file i found it written;but now when i build the app, with gradle or ant, it gives error

Answer (score 0):

Each version of cordova android platform require that you use a specific version of android sdk tools/API and you can't change it so you have to download the required api.

For version 6.3.0 it is API 26, if you really want to use an older API, you will have to use older version of android platform (eg for cordova android 6.2.3 it was API 25, cordova android 5.0.1 it was API 23...)

You can check [the android platform release notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md) for more info.

when you type `cordova platform add android` without providing a version, it downloads the latest version wich is now 6.2.3, so `cordova platform add android` and `cordova platform add android@6.2.3` do exactly the same. If you wanted to use the version 5.0.1 of the cordova android platform, you would have to type `cordova platform add android@5.0.1`

Comment: i have tried `cordova platform add android@5.0.1` already. Its for that only I said it gives a huge error message in red color

Comment: i have fixed the problem by changing the android version in config.xml, platforms.json, AndroidManifest.xml, and project.properties in *platforms\android\CordovaLib* and *platforms/android*.But now i am getting error in building the app via gradle or ant

Comment: Sorry I read too fast about the @5.0.1... I don't remember at what version exactly but there's been a change from using the old android sdk to using android studio, maybe your problem comes from that?

Comment: this is the error:  .java:503: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype